# Hiding text file in image

Tags: php, encryption

How can I make something like http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/HideIt.aspx in PHP?

What do I need for this? http://www.pctipstricks.net/hacking/trick-hide-text-images-steganography/

Comment: You have 2 great articles that explain the solution. You want us to do the fun part?

Comment: Try writing some code and seeing what you can do. Then post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the second result I found when searching google for "php stenography"

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3312-PHP-Hide-encrypted-data-in-images-using-steganography.html

Comment: maybe: http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&q=stenography+php&btnG=Google+Search